# Use ñ characters in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using SQLite to compare some ids (varchar 50) so I get a numeric database id.
I'm using C# and visual studio 2003. Pretty new in C# so maybe I'm doing a newbie mistake.

When doing some comparison like the following

```
SELECT * FROM tblUSer WHERE Use_id like '%Ñ120%'
```

I don't get anything even if this exist... I suppose is an encoding problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

I can't change the database schema since is not my database (need to modify select some data and update a field).

I can't change the data per se since it is a data that already exist and the user codes are the same as some reference like a club id or something...

Changing the data to UTF-8 worked to make it do the query (without it it would give an error) but still I don't get the desired data. Maybe is also how the data is saved by the original program.

What do I do so my query works with the Ñ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if your remove the N from your query and just check

```
Use_id LIKE '%120%'
```

and then select the appropriate ones in C#?

Comment: The Ñ can also be A or B or C or any other letter/number :S so it won't work like that

Comment: It will work if you look for the N~ character in C#. If you're facing an unmodifiable non UTF-8 database, this may be the only choice you have. You can start playing with various encodings (which is always great fun), but getting the SQLite ADO.NET adapter to speak in an encoding you want to the database may be a challenge.

Comment: thats true :S but still im trying :S i think the real problem is to guess which encoding used the original program :S but oh well im going to see if anyone can help me figure it out if not i will do it that way... thnx

Comment: Indeed is a true challenge to make SQlite ADO .NET to speak how i want it, so i did a manual search for the N~ and then do a replace for � that is how it is encoded in the database... this is the only odd char it solves my problem ... later i'll try to look for a universal solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblUSer WHERE Use_id like N'%Ñ120%'
```

Notice the N letter.

Comment: I am sure this is a valid SQL query.. Why it gives you "Sintax" Error That I do not know.. Does it say where is the error exactly?

Comment: i think not, im not sure. Any fast way to know this?

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/16/sql-server-find-collation-of-database-and-table-column-using-t-sql/

Comment: but mine is sqlite not sql server.there is a copy of a test db [here](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=P0XP7PMP)

Comment: Sorry, I am clueless about Sqlite

Comment: no problem, thanks anyway. Im also clueless in sqlite :S jeje it seems that only accepts utf8 or utf16 ... still i did a workaround that work for now till i find a good solution

Answer (score 0):

You should write in this way:

```
    SELECT * FROM tblUSer WHERE Use_id like N'%Ñ120%'
```

Comment: First N must be capital (not n)

Comment: About the above the N must be capital (not n). Anyway you can use application-defined SQL function like(Y,X) instead

Comment: I put it N not n, just doing it with c# ado.net